# Get PHP session variable with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the "Advanced Security PHP Register/Login System" which says you can get the SESSION id by using the following:

```
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

I need to get the user_id into my front end using AJAX. My application has the following AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
       url : 'login/get_user.php',
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'json',
       success : function (result) {
       alert(result['user']);
       },
       error : function () {
       alert("error");
       }
       })
```

And the PHP script looks as follows (users.php):

```
<?php 

$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$return_data = array();
$return_data['user'] = $userId;

echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();

?>
```

But I only get "error" in my alert when I load the page. The user is signed in successfully using the system. Are the SESSION variables global? Where does the php script need to sit to access the user_id so that the AJAX can get the proper response?

Comment: you need to use session_start(); in your users.php, and in your js while getting result value, your return is an object, so retrieving is like result.user

Comment: The error part of the jquery ajax is usually fired because it couldn't reach the endpoint (i.e. could not find login/get_user.php) - check in your browser dev tools (http://getfirebug.com/ or chrome dev tools) to see if the response is actually coming back (it might be error 404, error 500 etc.) OR you can edit the error function of the javascript to this: `error: function(xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr); console.log(status); console.log(err); }` then look in your browsers javascript console to see what the actual error is

Comment: So it's working now. Thank you everyone for your helpful comments. I put the new error: function into the AJAX call as suggested by @IaMaCuP and realized that the response (as shown in response text) I was getting was everything in that script (which has html in addition to the $user_id code). I put the snippet of PHP in it's own dedicated file and it's working perfectly. I also put session_start() as the beginning so thank you ameenulla0007